# Looking for title of TV series about boy and an alternative world

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe

In the middle of 2000 - 2010 I saw a TV series about a boy, who after school went to work for an old man at a shop. I don't remember clearly but shop sells old artifacts, books, suchlike.

This boy found a book. He read this book and in it a movie plays, based in an alternative fantasy world. In this world there is a war. I think they used modern guns in the war. Also I remember dragon or something like that.

The alternative world and this boy were connected in some mysterious way.

Maybe someone know about this series?

These series was recorded by live, not animated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've touched up some of your english so the question reads better. I hope it's still the questiojn you intended it to be!

Comment: Thanks @Pureferret I hope someone remmember this TV series.

Comment: Sounds like this horrible cartoon on PBS, Frannys Feet!  She visits her granddad in his cobbler shop and experiences adventures based on the shoes.  Makes me want to scream watching it, it is such tripe.  But my son likes it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like The Neverending Story. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088323/ 
The boy takes a book from an old man at a shop and then reads the story and finds out he is affecting the story and connected to it. There is a Luck Dragon but no guns and it is not a tv show but a movie made in the 80's. So if it's not right please try to add some details with a few more differences.

Edit: It looks like there was a live action TV show as well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Neverending_Story It was filmed in 2000 and matches everything except I'm not sure of the guns.

Comment: I found [Tales from the Neverending Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Neverending_Story). I think this is what I want. Very thanks. I see trailer, where is some modern mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested: the series was based on a book called The Never-Ending Story (Die unendliche Geschichte) by German writer Michael Ende. There are some differences between the series and the book, that might make it worth your while to read it :)