# What movie featured a Pegasus dying in quicksand?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This has literally been bugging me for a good few weeks. I used to be obsessed with this movie that my dad showed me. It has two main boys in it if I remember correctly, and there was a Pegasus that died in quicksand/mud.

I know it has something to do with time, but I can't remember the name and I can't find answers anywhere else!

Comment: Neverending story?

Comment: Was it a book or a movie?

Comment: Almost certainly the Neverending Story.  Wasn't a pegasus, just a normal horse, but it dying in the mud is probably one of the top traumatic movie moments for 80s kids.

Comment: @Adamant It was a book. *The Neverending Story* was never made into a movie. Such a magical and fantastic tale could never be made into a movie.

Comment: @starpilotsix: can confirm — was an eighties kid, had to watch The Neverending Story several times in elementary school, found it so terrifying that I’ve not been able to re-watch it to this day.

Comment: @PLL I've always thought The Neverending Story was really a case study in psychological horror.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/looking-for-title-of-tv-series-about-boy-and-an-alternative-world

Comment: The amount of answering in the comments in this thread http://i.imgur.com/AZhDupv.png

Answer (score 33):

As others have pointed out in comments, you seem to be describing this scene from the hit 1984 film [**The Neverending Story**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_NeverEnding_Story_(film)).

For the record, Artax was a **horse**, not a pegasus. You may be conflating his scenes with later ones from the film which feature a flying "[luck dragon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsVLb5ibKfM)".

The two main protagonists are Bastian (a young boy who we observe reading the titular book) and Atreyu (the hero of the book).

Comment: This was to be mu guess... :) Lets see if we are right!

Comment: The Swamps of Sadness. Has any other children's story featured a horse dying of *despair*? (also, I've always wondered if the Swamps of Sadness were inspired -- possibly even in-universe, given that this is Fantasia -- by clinical depression.)

Comment: The real kick in the gut is that in the book, Atrax can talk, and pleads for Atreyu to leave so as to not watch Atrax die.